# Program won't run in NetBeans, but runs on the command line!

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

So, I'm starting a C++ class right now, and I've configured NetBeans (which I use normally for PHP and Java Development) to use the Cygwin compiler/debugger. This is my first structured experience with C++, and I'm running into a slight issue. When I attempt to run a program within NetBeans (F11 or the Green Triangle) the project builds correctly, no errors or warnings, but then won't run. I receive the following error:

> The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
>   This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
>   Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 
>   This may give some additional information.
>
> C:/Users/Eric/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CS217ASeminar1/dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cs217aseminar1
>
> RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,515, total time: 58ms)

When I attempt to execute the given file within a command shell, I get no errors and the program runs successfully. The research I've done on this error usually indicates that C:\cygwin and/or C:\cygwin\bin (my install directories) aren't in the path. However, I've verified that I they've been added to the path, and I can run arbitrary programs from both of those folders.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this error, or any experience with something similar? Obviously, it's not a huge deal, but I'd like to be able to use NetBeans's built in functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: After tinkering a bit with the settings of my project in an attempt to fix it, it appears that the error was being caused by the Profiler in NetBeans. Since that only works on Linux/Solaris, and this is a Windows 7 box, disabling that caused no loss of functionality and solved the issue. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

Comment: Instead of putting `[Solved]` in the question title, you should answer your own question and accept the answer. This way the question and answer will be useful to other people with similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll do that now. Never solved my own question before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering a bit with the settings of my project in an attempt to fix it, it appears that the error was being caused by the Profiler in NetBeans. Since that only works on Linux/Solaris, and this is a Windows 7 box, disabling that caused no loss of functionality and solved the issue. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project change set configuration from debug to release. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong, but it sounds like your path might not be set correctly...

[Netbeans docs](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html)