# C++ program gives a run-time error when strings are used

Tags: c++, string, netbeans, mingw

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
    string st = "Hello world";
    return 0; 
}
```

and

```
#include <string> 
int main () 
{ 
    std::string st = "Hello world";
    return 0; 
}
```

I tried compiling this code using minGW compiler on netbeans. It brings up the following error after the successful build.

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 93ms)

But it works clean when strings are not used. I would like to know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich version of mingw are you using?

Comment: `std::string` is declared in `<string>`, not `<string.h>` - does this help? (Even if it doesn't, you should change this)

Comment: I use 4.8.1 I tried <string> but it does not work as well same error

Comment: there is something wrong with your setup, maybe another libstdc++ in your path?

Comment: Nope mingw is the only c++ compiler it has resolved and I have installed. (I have visual studios could it have made any influence?)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I have the same error code and everything. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @4castle Nope, I started using visual studio. You can also try Clion and Qt as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use c++ strings and don't use `using namespace std`:

```
#include <string> //c++ string header

int main () 
{ 
    std::string st = "Hello world";
    return 0; 
}
```

[`#include <string.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) is the old C-style string header and most likely isn't what you want to use here. See this question for more details: [Difference between <string> and <string.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257665/difference-between-string-and-string-h)

Note: If you really wanted the old C-style strings then you really should be using `#include <cstring>` because this will put those functions into the `std` namespace and won't cause any namespace pollution that can lead to other undesirable outcomes.

Likely what happened was that you used the old style string header and didn't properly initialize those strings. The old C-style strings don't have a constructor and operator= defined like the `std::string` class.

Edit: After looking at the Netbeans forum this is a problem with Netbeans and not a c++ issue. Try changing the output to an external terminal in Netbeans. Or run the program directly from the command line. If these approaches don't fix the problem or are undesirable then make a post over on the Netbeans forum. Also have a look at this question: [Program won't run in NetBeans, but runs on the command line!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411386/program-wont-run-in-netbeans-but-runs-on-the-command-line)

Comment: I still get the same error, I tried printing floats, ints and 
cout << "Hello world" works fine but 
string str = "Hello world"; gives an error

Comment: @user3248168 does the code I posted here produce the same error value when used verbatim?

Comment: yes it does!
RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 88ms)

Comment: @user3248168, this sounds very much like an issue with either your Netbeans configuration or installation.

Comment: Then I'll re install a compiler. Shall I try Cygwin instead of minGW as it is possible to be the reason?

Comment: If you are using only c++ I'd recommend codeblocks, I've found that to be really good.

Answer (score 0):

Uss `#include <string>` instead of string.h

Comment: I tried <string> but it does not work as well! I get the same error

Comment: also using std::string instead of the namespace?

Comment: Are you eble to run a return 0 program? your mingw linking/runtime may be corrupted. the code seems ok.