# C++ Run failed when using string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/) work with Netbeans+MinGW. It says run failed. I tried to do step by step and came up with this little code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string input = "";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting `RUN FAILED (exit value 57, total time: 364ms)`.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468868/c-program-gives-a-run-time-error-when-strings-are-used) I read that not use `using namespace std;`. I tried that way too, but still run failed. What is the problem? How to use string without run failed?

Comment: does it work without  `string input = "";` ?

Comment: @George Yes, it does.

Comment: This can't normally fail, so you most likely have either your compiler (MinGW) or IDE (NetBeans) setup wrong. Might be incomplete MinGW installation - did you install using the provided installer, or manually from zip archives? E.g. string might be using libraries (locale etc.) which you didn't install properly (missing, wrong version etc.).

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in netbeans?

Comment: Do you know if the one failing is the compilation process or the execution of the program itself? Make sure that you are compiling for C++, not for C.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. The line `string input="";` might be optimized out, but the run should return 0 to environment. Check you Mingw installation.

Comment: Btw. how are you running? From NetBeans in debug mode? (might be that NetBeans doesn't communicate properly with MinGW GDB, at least I always had problems getting that work in Eclipse under Windows). The running time might also point to that, as GDB might try to init the debug sessiion and failed somehow.

Comment: I.e. try to run the compiled program outside of NetBeans on the command line to see if it still fails, then try to run it in command line GDB - then you can diagnose if it is caused by either wrong MinGW installation, or failing GDB, or problem in NetBeans.

Comment: @axalis I used the provided MinGW installer, and I installed everything from the basic setup.

Comment: @axalis I ran simply with run project, but now i tried to debug and it said: `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.` And I tried to run outside Netbeans and it says `The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

Comment: @SimonÁdám you can fix that error with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

Comment: @cuongptnk I've added `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to the compiler options. I did clean and build and it worked outside Netbeans. Then I tried run project in Netbeans, it also worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes, that in general means you are missing some parts of MinGW in the installation (maybe the DLL is not installed by default). Apparently the missing part might be gcc-core-<version>-mingw32-dll.

Comment: @axalis I think the problem was that I didn't add the MinGW to PATH. But It's better if a program don't need dependencies like this so my program can work on other computers too.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, it would take forever and a waste of time to figure these problems out. A simple solution is trying other IDE. For C++, try [Code Block](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or [Visual Studio Express](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/visualstudio/). I did have a lot of weird errors with string library in Code Block, but in Visual Studio it runs well. The problem was that there are some errors in Code Block itself.

Comment: As far as Visual Studio is concerned, you can now even try the new 2017 version which has a completely new compiler flag for improved ISO conformance to replace the old `/Za` flag which never worked right with standard and/or Windows headers.

Comment: Although we found a solution now, I keep your advice and move to Visual Studio, because other problems can occur. And I don't have days to find a solution for every bloomer like this.